# How to create dynamic buttons and set value to buttons from database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have created dynamic buttons in php but i want to fetch value from databse and set it to the buttons but it didnt fetch and set.give any solution for this. In databse there is 5 values and that value i want to set to the buttons

following code i have tried.

```
<?php

function dash()
{
    include 'config.php';
    $sql = "SELECT  roomno FROM roombook";
    if($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $str='';
                $roomno=array($row['roomno']) ;
                // $aa=array($roomno);
                //echo "$arr";
                while(list($k,$v)=each($roomno)) {
                    $str.='<input type="submit" name="btn_'.$k.'" value="'.$v.'" id="btn_'.$k.'"/>';
                }
                return $str;
            }

            // Free result set
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        } else{
            echo "No records matching your query were found.";
        }
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($db);
    //$btn=array(1=>'hjck',2=>'102',3=>'104');
}
?>
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="bpanel" >
<?php echo dash();?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And the Problem with the code is?

Comment: the value is not set

Comment: What are some example contents of the `roomno` column please.

Comment: it like 1,2,3,4

Comment: Yikes, major database design mistake!

Comment: i will show you database file

Comment: `each()` works on arrays not strings look at `explode(',', $row['roomno'])` instead

Comment: It will show only one database value and create one button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `roonno` is a comma delimited list an `explode()` is what you need to do here

```
$sql = "SELECT  roomno FROM roombook";
if($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
    $str = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        // generate array from comma delimited list
        $rooms = explode(',', $row['roomno']);

        foreach ( $rooms as $k=>$v ) {
            $str .= '<input type="submit" name="btn_'.$k.'" value="'.$v.'" id="btn_'.$k.'"/>';
        }
    }
    return $str;
} else {
    //echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    // fixed? $link shoudl be $db
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($db);
}
```